# Find and return the elements that are repeated exactly twice in the list

Tags: python, arrays, duplicates

I want to find  and return the elements that are repeated exactly
twice in the list. I wrote this code but it also outputs the numbers that repeat three times.

How do I print out numbers that only repeat twice?

```
def printRepeating(arr,size) : 
count = [0] * size 
print(" Repeating elements are ",end = "") 
for i in range(0, size) : 
    if(count[arr[i]] == 1) : 
        print(arr[i], end = " ") 
    else : 
        count[arr[i]] = count[arr[i]] + 1

 arr = [2, 8, 4, 6, 1, 2, 8, 4, 7, 9, 4, 5] 
 arr_size = len(arr) 
 printRepeating(arr, arr_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, it is more concise:

```
import collections

arr = [2, 8, 4, 6, 1, 2, 8, 4, 7, 9, 4, 5] 
repeats = [
    item 
    for item, count in collections.Counter(arr).items() 
    if count == 2
]
print(repeats)
```

Comment: counter = collections.Counter(arr).items() is counting how many repeats all element has.
dict_items([(2, 2), (8, 2), (4, 3), (6, 1), (1, 1), (7, 1), (9, 1), (5, 1)])
the rest is a list comprehension that iterate over the dictionary and fech only the ones with count==2

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [2, 8, 4, 6, 1, 2, 8, 4, 7, 9, 4, 5] 
[x for x in set(arr) if arr.count(x) == 2]

Out[1]:
    [2, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want just to remove duplicates you can use

```
arr = [2, 8, 4, 6, 1, 2, 8, 4, 7, 9, 4, 5] 
set(arr)
```

otherwise use the collection method advised

Answer (score 0):

an other short solution :

```
arr = [2, 8, 4, 6, 1, 2, 8, 4, 7, 9, 4, 5] 
print(set([x for x in arr if arr.count(x) == 2])) # set is used to remove duplicates
# print(list(set([x for x in arr if arr.count(x) == 2]))) to print it as a list
```